# An English Version of Shiplashastra on Art and making practical things

Tags: scripture, resource, art, shilpa-shastras

Is there a shilpashastra online with English translation which deals with sketching devtas and doing artwork as well as making practical things like clothes and tools. I am also wondering if men can do shilpashastras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manasara is the most important treatise on Shilpasastra. It was translated into English by Prasanna Kumar Acharya.

Here are the links -

[Online English translation from wisdomlib](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manasara-english-translation)
[pdf format English translation](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.31241/page/n7/mode/1up?view=theater)